Unable to scrape table data from a website using BeautifulSoup
I am a beginner in Python, and would like to scrape a table data from a website, using BeautifulSoup. Below is my python code which doesn't work. Could anyone please help me on this?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tfex.co.th/en/products/equity/set50-index-options/S50U24C850/historical-trading'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

price_table = soup.find('div',class_ = 'historical-trading-table-SET50IO')     

print(price_table)     


for j in price_table.find_all('tbody'):    
    rows = j.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        date = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'table-b-table-default b-table-sticky-column td-class mxn-date fs-14px default-font-family text-deep-gray text-nowrap column-sticky ps-7')[1].text
        open_price = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[2].text
        high_price = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[3].text
        low_price = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[4].text
        close_price = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[5].text
        sp_close_price = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[6].text
        chg_price = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[7].text
        chg_percentage = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[8].text
        volume_contracts = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[9].text
        OI_contracts = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'text-end mxn-value pe-4')[10].text
        print(date, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, sp_close_price, chg_price, chg_percentage, colume_contracts, OI_contracts)
    


Does it need to be scraped or can you just use an iframe and link to the live data?

If the goal is getting that data into the current page, iframe is one line of code -->         

In fact, there are so many pages of the similar kinds of table data from which I 'd like to extract. This is just one example page. Using the Excel export button means that I have to do it manually page by page. That is why I need a Python BeautifulSoup code that works. By the way, I don't know anything about the Iframe, would you please suggest?

This page generates the table dynamically by referencing cookies and API.
Next u need get data from https://www.tfex.co.th/api/set/tfex/series/XXXXXX/historical-trading where XXXX ii ur case - S50U24C850. For this example, I'll use the Pandas for transform JSON to table.
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.tfex.co.th/api/set/tfex/series/S50U24C850/historical-trading"
headers = {
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'priority': 'u=1, i',
  'referer': 'https://www.tfex.co.th/en/products/equity/set50-index-options/S50U24C850/historical-trading',
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=requests.get('https://www.tfex.co.th/en/products/equity/set50-index-options/S50U24C850/historical-trading').cookies.get_dict())

df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['data'])
print(df.to_string())

OUTPUT:
                         date      symbol  open  high   low    average  close  settlementPrice  change  percentChange  totalVolume      oi pricePattern settlementPattern thbSettlementPrice exchangeRate deliveryVolume deferredChargeReceiver
0   2024-06-05T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  10.2  10.6   8.5   9.506024    9.4              9.4     0.3       3.296703        249.0   950.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
1   2024-06-04T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  12.0  12.6   8.9   9.543087    9.0              9.1    -2.1     -18.750000        311.0   920.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
2   2024-05-31T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  12.6  13.2  11.0  11.422436   11.2             11.2    -0.8      -6.666667        312.0  1132.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
3   2024-05-30T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  11.8  12.0  10.1  10.873826   12.0             12.0    -0.8      -6.250000        149.0   872.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
4   2024-05-29T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  14.0  14.0  12.8  13.480000   12.8             12.8    -2.9     -18.471338         55.0   754.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
5   2024-05-28T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.0  17.0  14.8  16.101481   15.7             15.7    -1.9     -10.795455        135.0   725.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
6   2024-05-27T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  16.1  17.6  16.0  16.626357   17.6             17.6     2.4      15.789474        129.0   647.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
7   2024-05-24T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  13.0  15.7  13.0  14.881481   15.2             15.2    -0.8      -5.000000         27.0   557.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
8   2024-05-23T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  15.6  16.8  15.6  16.272000   16.0             16.0    -2.4     -13.043478         25.0   543.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
9   2024-05-21T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  20.0  20.0  17.4  18.578571   18.3             18.4    -3.2     -14.814815         84.0   537.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
10  2024-05-20T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  24.0  24.0  21.5  22.166667   21.6             21.6    -0.7      -3.139013         21.0   478.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
11  2024-05-17T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  19.9  22.4  19.9  21.136000   22.4             22.3     1.8       8.780488         25.0   465.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
12  2024-05-16T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  19.0  22.2  19.0  21.152459   20.5             20.5     2.2      12.021858         61.0   462.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
13  2024-05-15T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  18.5  18.8  18.1  18.554167   18.3             18.3    -0.7      -3.684211         24.0   434.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
14  2024-05-14T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.5  19.0  17.5  18.493750   19.0             19.0     2.0      11.764706         16.0   415.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
15  2024-05-13T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.0  17.0  17.0  17.000000   17.0             17.0     1.0       6.250000         20.0   400.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
16  2024-05-10T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  15.6  15.7  15.6  15.650000   15.7             16.0     NaN            NaN          2.0   380.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
17  2024-05-09T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  15.1  17.6  15.1  16.585714   16.0             16.0     NaN            NaN          7.0   381.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
18  2024-05-08T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.7  17.7  16.0  17.467485   16.0             16.0    -2.6     -13.978495        163.0   385.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
19  2024-05-07T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.0  20.0  17.0  18.284615   18.6             18.6     3.2      20.779221         26.0   278.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
20  2024-05-03T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  14.6  15.4  14.5  15.305263   15.4             15.4     1.5      10.791367         38.0   288.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
21  2024-05-02T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  15.7  15.7  13.9  14.188889   13.9             13.9    -1.8     -11.464968          9.0   294.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
22  2024-04-30T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  14.0  16.5  14.0  15.497436   15.7             15.7     1.7      12.142857         39.0   294.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
23  2024-04-29T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  13.5  16.0  12.6  14.603704   14.0             14.0     0.3       2.189781         81.0   309.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
24  2024-04-26T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  14.6  14.8  13.6  14.320000   13.7             13.7    -1.1      -7.432432         15.0   278.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
25  2024-04-25T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  15.0  15.4  14.8  15.020000   14.8             14.8     0.3       2.068966         30.0   268.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
26  2024-04-24T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  16.5  16.5  14.5  14.826923   14.5             14.5    -0.3      -2.027027         26.0   240.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
27  2024-04-23T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  14.0  15.5  13.3  14.310870   14.8             14.8     2.3      18.400000         46.0   245.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
28  2024-04-22T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  12.0  12.5  12.0  12.285185   12.5             12.5     2.2      21.359223         27.0   219.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
29  2024-04-19T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  10.2  13.0   8.8  10.768571   10.3             10.3    -3.7     -26.428571         35.0   201.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
30  2024-04-18T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.0  17.0  11.5  13.738776   14.0             14.0    -3.0     -17.647059        147.0   204.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
31  2024-04-17T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  18.0  18.0  15.0  16.512500   17.0             17.0    -5.9     -25.764192         24.0   108.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
32  2024-04-11T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  27.2  27.2  22.9  25.700000   22.9             22.9    -6.2     -21.305842         10.0    93.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
33  2024-04-10T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.100000   29.1             29.1    -0.9      -3.000000          1.0    90.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
34  2024-04-09T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  22.0  30.0  22.0  25.235714   30.0             30.0    12.8      74.418605         14.0    99.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
35  2024-04-05T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.7  17.8  17.2  17.700000   17.2             17.2    -0.4      -2.272727         22.0   102.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
36  2024-04-04T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.3  18.0  16.6  17.400000   17.6             17.6    -0.7      -3.825137          8.0    82.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
37  2024-04-03T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN    NaN             18.3    -1.7      -8.500000          NaN    74.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
38  2024-04-02T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  20.2  20.2  20.2  20.200000   20.2             20.0     0.1       0.502513         20.0    75.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
39  2024-04-01T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  17.9  20.9  17.9  19.855556   20.0             19.9     1.5       8.152174          9.0    56.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
40  2024-03-29T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850  18.8  20.4  18.3  19.786538   18.3             18.4     1.1       6.358382         52.0    52.0      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None
41  2024-03-28T00:00:00+07:00  S50U24C850   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN    NaN             17.3    -2.8     -13.930348          NaN     NaN      #,##0.0          #,##0.00               None         None           None                   None

